# Failed CSS link on atom

Tags: css, hyperlink

So I'm new to coding but this seems like a no brainer that I can't seem to work out. I created a proper link saved in a styles.css file but the background color isn't coming up. when I inspect the page it just tells me it can't find the file. What could I possibly be doing wrong here?

And here's the site I'm starting--->

[My site](https://C:%5CUsers%5CHopkins%27%20Family%5CDesktop%5CCoding%20program%5CCSS-My%20site%5CCSS%5Cindex.html)

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">  It keeps saying "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Double check your directory structure and the name of the css file. That error means you are providing the wrong path or filename.